# Circle shifting of letters in a given word

Tags: c++

so I had this homework to shift the letters in a given word. On the first line I have to input a string (containing n letters from latin alphabet), and on the second line I have to input a row of m integers k - count of the shifts that the program has to perform. The input can have N examples.

Constraints:

0 < n < 1000000

0 < m < 1000000

-1 < k < 1000000

0 < N < 100

Example of input:

abracadabra

4 1 0

Floccinaucinihilipilification

10 20

Output of the upper example:

cadabraabra

bracadabraa

abracadabra

inihilipilificationFloccinauc

ificationFloccinaucinihilipil

Now, here's my code that I've written, which should be working correctly, however it doesn't ^^ :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

string m;

void reverse(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    unsigned i, j, k, c;
    char tmp;
    for (c=(b-a)/2, k=a, j=b, i=0; i<c; i++, j--, k++)
    {
        tmp = m[k];
        m[k] = m[j];
        m[j] = tmp;
    }
}

void shift(unsigned k, int n)
{
    reverse(0, k-1);
    reverse(k, n-1);
    reverse(0, n-1);
}

int main()
{
    int N;

    while(getline(cin, m))
    {
        int n = m.length();
        if (n <= 0 || n >= 1000000)
        {
            break;
        }

        string strnumbers;
        cin>>strnumbers;
        int buffer;
        vector<int> numbers;
        istringstream iss(strnumbers);
        while (iss >> buffer ) numbers.push_back(buffer);
        if(numbers.size() >= 1000000)
        {
            break;
        }
        vector<char> result;
        for(vector<int>::size_type s = 0; s < numbers.size(); s++)
        {
            if(numbers[s] < -1 || numbers[s] > 1000000)
            {
                break;
            }
            shift(numbers[s], n);
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) result.push_back(m[i]);
        }
        for(vector<char>::size_type s = 0; s != result.size(); s++)
        {
            cout<<result[s];
        }
        N++;
        if (N == 100)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

First of all, it doesn't print all the answers. If I use the first example (abracadabra
 4 1 0) it outputs only the first line, and there's the second problem. Instead of outputting "cadabraabra" it outputs "cadabraarba". What am I doing wrong and is there any way that I can solve this easier? Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: first thing you are using global variable m,which is manipulated by the first shift call for next shift call you have modified value of m.

Comment: Would using [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) be considered cheating? ;)

Comment: Nope, guess not ^^

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way that I can solve this easier? ?

Sure, don't reinvent the wheel, use [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

```
std::string str;
while (std::getline(std::cin, str))
{
    int number;
    while (std::cin >> number)
    {
        std::string tmp{str};
        std::rotate(tmp.begin(), tmp.begin() + number, tmp.end());

        std::cout << tmp << "\n";
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Live at coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ef512538138b273)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string shift(const string & in,int s)
{
    int length=in.size();
    int rotate=s%length;
    string result;
    if(rotate == 0)
    {
        result=in;
    }
    else
    {

        result=in.substr(rotate)+in.substr(0,rotate);
    }
    return result;
}

int main ()
{
  std::string a="abcdefghi";
  std::cout<<shift(a,1)<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```